# How would i create a javascript button that shows text on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

How can i make this button display paragraph text when clicked?
The `onClick` is not being recorded and I cannot even see the alert message when I click the button.

```js
function displaySong1() {
  alert("asdasf");
}
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: #8C6D09;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: #8C6D09;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<button class=".button .button1" onClick="displaySong1()">Easy</button>
```

Comment: try using onclick instead of onClick

Comment: do you get any error in the console? the alert comes up without any issues in my browser....

Comment: Make sure to change onClick to onclick (all lowercase)

Comment: show your console error you have a conflict of jquery

Answer (score -1):

you just have to set a paragraph with display:none and set to display:block when you click.

```js
function displaySong1() {
  var p = document.getElementById("paragraph");
  p.style.display = "block";    
}
```

```css
.button {
    background-color: #8C6D09;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:4px 2px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
     transition-duration: 0.4s; 
}
     
.button1{
   background-color:#8C6D09;
    color:#FFF;     
}

#paragraph
{
  display:none;
}

just change display:none to display:block on the paragraph
```

```html
<button class="button button1" onclick="displaySong1()">Easy</button>
<div id="paragraph">
hello
</div>
```

Comment: here is the full code as it still does not seem to work:

Comment: I forgot a semicolon, actually.

Comment: @demis if this example is not working for you the problem is not in the js.

Answer (score -1):

You should avoid to use dot when you give the classname of specific tag..

`<button class="button button1" onClick="displaySong1()">Easy</button>`

Answer (score -1):

You use `.createElement` and `.appendChild`.

```js
function displaySong1() {
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  var t = document.createTextNode("asdf");
  p.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: #8C6D09;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: #8C6D09;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<button class=".button .button1" onClick="displaySong1()">Easy</button>
```